# Are there tessellations of the plane with curved $C^1$ shapes?

Tags: reference-request, plane-geometry, plane-curves, tiling, tessellations

Does there exist a $C^1$ curve $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^1  \to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the plane can be tessellated by a union of congruent shapes, each has boundary identical to $\text{Image}(\alpha)$ up to translation and rotation?

**Where can I find a classification of such creatures?**

I might be a bit imprecise in my formulation, but I hope that the essential question is clear:

We all know that there are regular polygonal tessellations of the plane. The question is whether one can use a "building-block shape" whose boundary is $C^1$, without "corners"?

Note that I do want all the building-blocks to be congruent, so they should be the same up to an isometric transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And I want the intersection between two such shapes in the tiling be only at the boundaries.

Intuitively, the thing I am looking for is something like that:

[image]

**Picture Source:**

(By Dmharvey - w:en:Image:Wallpaper_group-p3-1.jpg, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=856136).

Comment: I don't think such a tessellation is possible. There is necessarily some point where $n \ge 3$ shapes meet; in a neighborhood of that point, shape boundaries divide the plane into $n$ angles. The only way for a corner not to exist is that all the angles be equal to $\pi$ radians. But this is impossible as the angles must sum to $2\pi$.

Comment: It seems to me that you are right. Somehow I am having trouble giving a rigorous argument that excludes the possibility of the angles to be $0,\pi,\pi$.

Comment: An angle of $0$ would correspond to a cusp in the shape. If you don't consider cusps to be corners, then there are solutions where four shapes meet at a point with the angles $0, 0, \pi, \pi$ such as [this one](https://i.imgur.com/RH9UHsy.png) (sorry for the quality). I don't know if there are any solutions with just one cusp.

Comment: Hmm, you made me think some more! And your added picture is very instructive! Thanks. Yes, I think that for my purposes these cusps should not be allowed...as they cannot have a smooth arclength parametrization (their images are not really $C^1$ submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: @pregunton Assuming that you have a deformation of an ordinary periodic tiling, it will use two cusps.. Even after deforming the tile, all the vertices of the tiling still need to have a total angle of $2\pi$ and the number of vertices and tiles in the fundamental parallelogram stays the same, so the deformation cannot affect the total angle that a single tile contributes. The deformed tile will therefore still have a total angle of $(n-2)\pi$ just like the n-gon it started off as. When all $n$ angles are deformed to have value $\pi$ or $0$, there will be two with value $0$, i.e. two cusps.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks! That is a very interesting argument. Can you please elaborate on why the total angle of a single tile do not change? I understand why around each vertex you still have $2\pi$. (but did not fully understand the argument regarding the "the number of vertices and tiles in the fundamental parallelogram stays the same"...). How do use that? I mean why cannot the total angle of a "larger" domain change?

Comment: @AsafShachar Consider a repeating section of the periodic tiling (e.g. a fundamental parallelogram). It will contain a finite number of tiles, and a finite number of tiling vertices (points where 3 or more tiles meet). The sum of all the angles in this repeating section can be counted in two ways: $2\pi$(number of vertices) = (number of tiles)(sum of interior angles of the tile). When you deform the edges in a tiling you do not change the number of vertices in the repeating section, nor the number of tiles. Therefore you also won't change the sum of the interior angles of the tile.

Comment: @AsafShachar Of course, if you deform it to a tiling that uses more than one type of tile you can have some with no cusps, but to compensate you will also have some with more than 2 cusps. If all tiles have only interior angles of $\pi$ or $0$, then there will be two cusps per tile on average within the repeating section of the tiling. Consider for example a periodic packing with circles, where the circles of course have no cusps but the areas in between have 3 or more.